# Linux On intel Macbook pro

Tags: linux, macos

I am facing problems booting any linux distro an my intel mac. i think it is not a hardware problem because i have the full specs macbook pro.

i tried many linux distro, (ubuntu, debian, manjaro, kali...) i boot them on a usb all fine and boot the mac in the distro it shows me the part where i want to chose the language and try or install but the cursor of the mouse doesnt move at all not even the buttons.

i am not even able to download the distro it just freezes immediately.

i tried boot managers like grub and nothing same freezing. i tried waiting a day on the boot menu and still nothing.

Comment: Ubuntu has a minimal text-only installer for situations like this one where normal installers don't work called the [Ubuntu Minimal USB](https://askubuntu.com/a/689263/). Another approach is to enable the `nomodeset` kernel boot option.

Comment: i will try the minimal USB but the nomodeset is it when ubuntu is already installed?
my problem is that it freezes before i am able to install it. it freezes on the chose language page

Comment: `nomodeset` is used only as a kernel boot option for booting a live USB installer for installing Linux distributions like Ubuntu. Since you mentioned that you want to try the Ubuntu minimal USB I will post about it here, but currently it is available only for the development release of the latest LTS version of Ubuntu which is Ubuntu 24.04.

Comment: Here are a few tips to get started. 1. The `dd` command is built-in in macOS. 2. To display the SHA256 checksum of a file named mini.iso in macOS run `openssl sha256 mini.iso` 3. When you insert the USB thumb drive into your computer to make an Ubuntu minimal USB, open up the Disk Utility to find out the exact device name of the USB thumb drive that you inserted. It may be something like disk2s**X** where X is replaced by an integer digit.

Comment: macOS uses `/dev` for identifying disk devices the same as Linux does. So if Disk Utility shows that the disk identifier of the USB thumb drive is disk2s2 then its disk device name in macOS is `/dev/disk2s2`